# Converting a list of tuples to a tuple of lists recursively

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I need a recursive function that returns a tuple of lists from a list of tuples. In other words, its type signature would be

```
func :: [(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])
```

Here is an example:

```
λ> func [(1,3), (2,4)]
([1,2], [3,4])
```

I made two functions to return a list of the first and second elements from the tuples and joining them, but I want only one recursive function to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’re looking for [`unzip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unzip):

```
unzip :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
```

As general advice, when you know a type signature and you’re wondering if there’s any already-existing function that has that type signature, [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is a good bet; [searching for that type signature](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%28a%2C+b%29%5D+-%3E+%28%5Ba%5D%2C+%5Bb%5D%29) finds `unzip` as its first and only result.

Comment: Can I find the unzip implementation? I searched for it but got no sucess.

Comment: @AnimeBear: Well, the implementation that GHC uses can be found by clicking the “Source” link on the right-hand-side of the `unzip` header in the documentation I linked to, which points to [this source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#unzip). It’s not very enlightening, though; an implementation with explicit recursion might look like `unzip [] = []; unzip ((a,b):xs) = (a:as, b:bs) where (as,bs) = unzip xs`.